# Firebase UI RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

Kindly help me here, am stuck.Am having a perfectly working Firebase UI recyclerview.So am iterating through the database before loading the items. I want to loop through all the items(then get the values of sum of mon + tuesday = start then get wed + thur = end for every individual item then only populate the view with values where start <= 90 && end <= 90).

This is the sample structure of my database

Database structure.

[image: Database Structure]

This is what i have tried but its not working.Note the button onclick and recyclerview works.The only problem is adding that condition.

The inner else condition seems to always be called, if i remove it, the if statement is always true regardless of the logic.So the (if - else) doesn't work.

```
   saturday.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

final DatabaseReference Distance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Days");

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        //Loop through the database to get all results

        Distance.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                Iterator<DataSnapshot> items = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

                while (items.hasNext()) {
                    DataSnapshot item = items.next();

                    if (item.child("mon").exists() && item.child("tue").exists() && item.child("wed").exists() && item.child("thur").exists()) {

                        //Start
                        Double mon = Double.valueOf(item.child("mon").getValue().toString());
                        Double tue = Double.valueOf(item.child("tue").getValue().toString());
                        Double start = (mon + tue);

                        //End
                        Double wed = Double.valueOf(item.child("wed").getValue().toString());
                        Double thur = Double.valueOf(item.child("thur").getValue().toString());
                        Double end = (wed + thur);

                        //Check for the values that are less than 90 for both start and end.
                        if (start <= 90 && end <= 90) {

                            //Load them into the recyclerview
                            Query query = Distance;

                            FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<recyclerDriver, Users_ViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<recyclerDriver, Users_ViewHolder>(

                                    recyclerDriver.class,
                                    R.layout.recyclerdriverlayout,
                                    Users_ViewHolder.class,
                                    query

                            ) {
                                @Override
                                protected void populateViewHolder(Users_ViewHolder viewHolder, recyclerDriver model, final int position) {
                                    viewHolder.setName(model.getName());
                                    viewHolder.setName(model.getName());
                                    viewHolder.setFrom(model.getDepartureLocation());
                                }
                            };

                            mRecyclerview.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
                            firebaseRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        } else {
                            message = "Sorry! No matches for you.";
                            snackbarShow(message);
                            mRecyclerview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    } else {
                        message = "Sorry! Some records are missing";
                        snackbarShow(message);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                snackbarShow(databaseError.getMessage().toString());
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: If you put a breakpoint then you can step walk the code and see where it fails?

Comment: @Erik Am trying to get all the children in the firebase object which meet that condition and display them all in the recyclerView.Thats why i didnt add a break.But i added a Toast that confirms am getting all the values both start and end respective to all children.The problem is filtering these inside the loop so that i only have the items meeting that condition displayed after the iteration.So the inner if else part is what is not working.

Comment: If you but a [breakpoint](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug) in the inner if you will see exactly what happens, the Toast is not enough as you notice

Comment: Adding a break in the inner makes it work but it  laods all the children that meet the database query, its as if the condition is overlooked.@Erik.